# Automatically log into SIP phone when user logs into Windows

Tags: windows, voip, asterisk, freepbx, login-script

We run an asterisk-based PBX, with FreePBX front end, configured in 'device and user mode' to support hot desking users. That is, a user arrives and sits at any desk, keys *11 into the phone (Cisco 7900 series) and logs in with their extension number and PIN. From that point, the user's calls arrive at that phone. When the user is done, they log off by keying *12 and their calls go to voicemail from that point.

What would be handy is if we could automate this login process, so that the users is automatically logged into a phone when they log into Windows. The PCs and phones are permanently assigned to desks, so I can work out which phone to use based on the PC thats being logged into. The user's extension number is stored in Active Directory and I always set the PIN the same as the extension number, so I have all the information necessary.

So what I need is some code that runs on windows, possibly in the login script, and connects the user to their phone.

Does anyone have anything like this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create desktop application to be runned at user's login.

In that aplication you can login user using astirisk AMI interface.

If application is too complex for you, you can create auto-expect script.